# Symfony2 assets:install changes reference

Tags: php, symfony, styles, assetic

I'm trying to use:

```
{% stylesheets '@Bundle/Resources/public/css/style.css' filter='rename_filter' %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ asset_url }}">
{% endstylesheets %}
```

After running assets:install the reference to the css file has change to /css/40ae858_style_1.css. Is there any way to use the original reference? At least when env=dev.

I'm not using assetic:dump while developing but will be using it on the production server.

Comment: Did you set anything for `rename_filter` in `config.yml`? If yes, would you provide the code?

Comment: Sorry. Forgot to remove that. I was trying to rename the file from a filter but discovered that the filters are loaded after the name has been generated.

Answer (score -1):

Your nearly there please use.

```
   {% stylesheets 'bundles/yourbundlename/css/*' filter='cssrewrite' %}
         <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset_url }}" />
   {% endstylesheets %}
```

Direct access 
       {{ asset('/bundles/yourbundlename/css/thefilename.css') }}

Comment: Could you explain why OP should use this? That won't solve their question - it will only rewrite the URL references inside of the CSS files.

Comment: that will still produce <link rel="stylesheet" href=" /css/40ae858_style_1.css" />

Comment: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/assetic/asset_management.html, but i'll edit my answer